# Computing stock returns from stock prices of multiple companies using a double for-Loop (without using a package)

Tags: r, stock

I have a matrix with multiple columns (each column represents a company) and multiple rows (consisting of stock prices)

I would like to calculate the Returns **without** the use of a package!

I try to do it with a double for-Loop, but it doesn't work, I get an error:

> "Error in Portf_Returns[i, j] <- Portf_ClosingPrices[i + 1, j]/Portf_ClosingPrices[i,  :
>     incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

```
# Trying to compute Returns in a matrix of stock Prices with double for-loop
ClosingPrices <- sample(10,30,10) # I generate some random stock prices

Portf_ClosingPrices <- matrix(ClosingPrices,nrow = 10, ncol = 3) # 3 companies (3 colums) and 10 stock prices for each company

Portf_Returns <- NULL
i <- 1
j <- 1
for (j in 1:3) {
  for (i in 1:9) {
    Portf_Returns[i,j] <- Portf_ClosingPrices[i+1,j] / Portf_ClosingPrices[i,j] - 1
  }
}
Portf_Returns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the matrix to return the values:

```
ClosingPrices <- sample(10,30,10) # I generate some random stock prices

Portf_ClosingPrices <- matrix(ClosingPrices,nrow = 10, ncol = 3) # 3 companies (3 colums) and 10 stock prices for each company

Portf_Returns <- matrix(NA,10,3)

for (j in 1:3) {
  for (i in 1:9) {
    Portf_Returns[i,j] <- Portf_ClosingPrices[i+1,j] / Portf_ClosingPrices[i,j] - 1
  }
}
Portf_Returns

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] -0.7500000  7.0000000 -0.8333333
 [2,]  2.0000000 -0.6250000  2.0000000
 [3,] -0.5000000  2.0000000  2.0000000
 [4,]  1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
 [5,]  0.6666667 -0.7777778 -0.2222222
 [6,] -0.6000000  2.0000000  0.2857143
 [7,] -0.7500000  0.5000000 -0.8888889
 [8,]  2.0000000 -0.5555556  7.0000000
 [9,]  2.0000000  0.2500000 -0.1250000
[10,]         NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much StupidWolf, what a fast response.
So initializing by just "Portf_Returns <- NULL" doesn't work for a matrix like this.
And initializing the "i <- 1" as well as "j <- 1" is not necessary.

I already applied the change to my real data and it works perfectly fine! How could I remove now the last row which consists of NA?

Comment: Yeah, you cannot insert values into NULL which has no dimensions.. hope that makes sense. You can remove the last row by doing Portf_Returns = Portf_Returns[-nrow(Portf_Returns),] or simply start with Portf_Returns <- matrix(NA,9,3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `nested sapply` which computes in the first stage the return over each row and then moves to another column. You don't need to specify the dimension of your output matrix.

```
sapply(1:3, function(j) sapply(2:10, function(i) Portf_ClosingPrices[,j][i] / Portf_ClosingPrices[,j][i-1] - 1)) -> Portf_Returns

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] -0.8000000  3.0000000  0.0000000
 [2,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.3333333
 [3,]  3.5000000  0.1250000 -0.6666667
 [4,] -0.1111111 -0.4444444  2.5000000
 [5,]  0.2500000  0.0000000  0.4285714
 [6,] -0.5000000  0.8000000 -0.1000000
 [7,]  0.8000000 -0.5555556  0.0000000
 [8,] -0.1111111 -0.2500000 -0.5555556
 [9,]  0.2500000  2.3333333  1.0000000
```

Replace 3 by `ncol(Portf_ClosingPrices)` and 10 by `nrow(Portf_ClosingPrices)` and you have this entirely dynamic.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
exp(diff(log(Portf_ClosingPrices))) - 1
```

output:

```
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,]  1.0000000 -0.6000000 -0.3000000
 [2,]  1.0000000  2.5000000 -0.4285714
 [3,] -0.5000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
 [4,]  1.0000000 -0.7142857  0.2500000
 [5,] -0.7500000  1.0000000  0.2000000
 [6,]  9.0000000  0.2500000 -0.1666667
 [7,] -0.3000000 -0.8000000  0.0000000
 [8,] -0.1428571  5.0000000 -0.4000000
 [9,]  0.1666667 -0.3333333  2.0000000
```